# Exiting Ruby delete_if when false condition is satisfied

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the following line of code that stores a list of reverse chronological timestamps and removes out of date timestamps by comparing the intervals between the stored timestamps and `Time.now - 5.minutes` (which is the "expired" timestamp to compare to)

```
@@timestamp[@name].delete_if { |ts| ts <= Time.now - 5.minutes }
```

Timestamps are added to this hash using:

```
@@timestamp[@name] << Time.now
```

So my question is, `delete_if` is sort of computationally intensive in my case, because `@@timestamp` is just a reverse chronological list of timestamps, and so if let's say I have a list of timestamps like:

```
{expired, expired, expired, not-expired, not-expired, not-expired}
```

I would like the `delete_if` to exit once it reaches the first `not-expired`, which means, when `ts <= Time.now - 5.minutes` returns `false`

Comment: What is `@@timestamp[@name]`?

Comment: Ah, by "list", you mean array.

Comment: No, wait, you wrote "this hash", so it must be a hash. Then, how can a key-value pair like `ts` be compared against a time?

Comment: And what is `{expired, expired, expired, not-expired, not-expired, not-expired}` supposed to be? It is not valid a Ruby construct. Is it a mathematical notation expressing a set? Then it should be equivalent to `{not-expired, expired}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@@timestamp[@name].drop_while { |ts| ts <= Time.now - 5.minutes }
```

See: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/drop_while:

> Drops elements up to, but not including, the first element for which the block returns `nil` or `false` and returns an array containing the remaining elements.

There is also [`Array#take_while`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/take_while), in case you need to invert the logic.

Comment: Wow thank you! Didn't know this existed. I was gonna do something like `delete_if {|x| break unless x <= Time.now - 5.minutes}` (which didn't work)

Comment: Just curious - does this modify the underlying array like `delete_if` does? I don't think it does. So I'd need to assign the new array back to `@@timestamp[@name]` right?

Comment: You are correct (the receiver is not mutated). See the doc. Whenever a method mutates the receiver the doc will make clear that it does.